# Block TTY echo to display

Tags: ubuntu, tty, display

I have a minimal Ubuntu as a Linux server. It starts many scripts on startup.  That is okay, but I want to disable tty1 to echo everything to display.

When I start this server, a login prompt is presented on tty1; and I want the display to be clear so nobody can see what is being typed into.

Comment: Watch for an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/442460/set-permanent-command-line-options-to-upstart I've changed your tag from debian to ubuntu since they do not use the same init system.

Answer (score 3):

As root, edit `/etc/default/grub` and to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` add:

```
--default-console=none
```

Then run `update-grub` and try a reboot.

I do not have a ubuntu system here to test this on, but I am pretty sure it should suppress output from `upstart` (the init daemon that runs your scripts), but not the kernel's initial boot messages.  To do that, also add

```
quiet loglevel=0
```

to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` *before* the `--default-console` bit, which should be last.